# Why indicative in a indirect question?

Tags: grammar-identification

In the ***repeat*** entry of Smith & Hall's *English-Latin dictionary* (which can be read in [Latinitium](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh21103)), there is an example:
[image]

According to grammar books, a verb in an indirect question should be subjunctive, except in early Latin and poetry, while indicative here instead. Is this sentence in either exceptional case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't actually an indirect question, but a relative clause: *quod dixit* "(that) which he said".

The two constructions are easy to confuse, especially since English can translate both with *what*. In this case, though, *quod* can only be a relative pronoun; the neuter interrogative pronoun is *quid*, so an indirect question like e.g. "I know what he said" would be *scio quid dixerit*.

Comment: I should review pronoun declensions however :<

Answer (score 4):

The relevant quote is:

> Sic igitur dicet ille quem expetimus […] ut quod dixit iteret…
> *Therefore the one that we're trying to discover speaks in such a way […] that he will repeat the thing that he's [already] said…*

In other words, this is a purpose clause (*sic…ut* + subj). And the object of the subjunctive verb *iteret* isn't an indirect question: it's a relative clause, as TKR said, with the relative pronoun *quod*. This can also be translated "what" in English, but it's the relative word, not the question word, which is why we can also translate it as "the thing that".